# How to get the element id by strong text using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

HTML:

```
<div id="testModal" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container ui-dialog-exam ui-draggable" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="testModal_title" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="polite" style="width: auto; height: auto; left: 495px; top: 362px; z-index: 1002; display: block;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top ui-draggable-handle"><span id="testModal_title" class="ui-dialog-title"></span></div><div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="height: auto;">
<form id="testForm" name="testForm" method="post" action="/pages/juht/test/test.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="testForm" value="testForm">

            
            
            <ul>

                    <li><a id="testForm:j_idt607:8:j_idt609" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('testForm',{'testForm:j_idt607:8:j_idt609':'testForm:j_idt607:8:j_idt609'}).submit('testForm');return false;PrimeFaces.onPost();">
                            <strong>10.10.2022</strong>
                            19:00
                            <strong>Place »</strong></a>
                    </li>
                    </li>
                    <li><a id="testtestForm:j_idt607:10:j_idt609" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget" onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('testForm',{'testForm:j_idt607:10:j_idt609':'testForm:j_idt607:10:j_idt609'}).submit('testForm');return false;PrimeFaces.onPost();">
                            <strong>11.10.2022</strong>
                            11:00
                            <strong>Place2 »</strong></a>

            </ul>
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" value="-4629203658604947866:263715935893442864" autocomplete="off"></form></div></div>
```

How can I print out the element id by just using strong text here?

Comment: I am getting error. element_id = element.get_attribute('id')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'. Did you mean: '__getattribute__'?

Comment: What version of selenium are you using? Do a pip freeze and tell me.

Comment: I am using selenium 4.3.0

Comment: Then the correct way of getting an attribute is indeed`get_attribute`. What's the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: I can't share the url because you have to login and you can't create account.

Comment: then share your full code, and the full HTML of that page.

Comment: I added the html part of it

Comment: that's not the full html code of the page. Also, where is your code? what have you tried until now? Looking at it as it is, my response should work. I cannot explain the error message you get, give you state you're using Selenium 4.

Comment: @Mrwolf _print out the element id_: Do you want to print `testForm:j_idt607:8:j_idt609` or `testtestForm:j_idt607:10:j_idt609`?

Comment: Glad to be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *id* attribute as the elements are dynamic you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- To print *`testForm:j_idt607:8:j_idt609`*:

  - Using *XPATH* and the text *19:00*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., '19:00')]"))).get_attribute("id"))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH* and the text *10.10.2022*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[.//strong[contains(., '10.10.2022')]]"))).get_attribute("id"))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH* and the text *Place »*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[.//strong[contains(., 'Place »')]]"))).get_attribute("id"))
    ```
- To print *`testtestForm:j_idt607:10:j_idt609`*:

  - Using *XPATH* and the text *11:00*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., '11:00')]"))).get_attribute("id"))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH* and the text *11.10.2022*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[.//strong[contains(., '11.10.2022')]]"))).get_attribute("id"))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH* and the text *Place2 »*:

    ```
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[.//strong[contains(., 'Place »')]]"))).get_attribute("id"))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You want the parent element's ID of that `<strong>` element? Then try:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='10.10.2022']::a")))
element_id = element.get_attribute('id')
```

You will need to also import the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```